# Sending and receiving bytes from a microcontroller

Tags: python, arduino, byte

I am using Python 3 to send bytes to a micro controller and then receive them back (and print them in my python monitor).  They go through the micro controller and it seems there is some weird behavior applied to it during this path.  For instance, when I do:

```
a = b'\7'
op(board).send(a) #This is syntax specific to the program that runs Python
```

and

```
print(received)
```

It prints out `b'7'` as expected.  However, when I try the same code but with `a = b'8'` it prints out: `b'9265'` and I have no idea what the difference is.

Similarly, for anyone who has experience using Arduino and Python, is there any explanation as to what format I could use to easily send Serial data to / from the Arduino? It seems as though I can only send `bytes` objects, but I am not sure how these are interpreted by the Arduino.  It looks as though the byte value is converted to its `utf-8` "symbol" value (i.e. as a string) then sent to the Arduino, which reads it is a binary value.

However, when I send this read value back to Python, it then sends a `byte` object with the decimal value.  Since this is the case and I may be receiving a stream of values (from an analog pin for instance) what is the best way to rapidly decode these byte values into decimals

In other words, this would be fine except I would have to call `chr(val)` on every value.
If I pass in the value `b'151'` (meaning I want a decimal value of `151` the arduino echoes back `b'495349'`
and using `int(chr(val))` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are using byte literals incorrectly. Check the [doc](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/). Here are some examples:

```
>>> list(b'\7')
[7]
>>> list(b'7')
[55]              # character '7'
>>> list(b'8')
[56]              # character '8'
>>> list(b'\8')
[92, 56]          # characters '\\' and '8' because \8 can't be parsed as octal number
>>> list(b'151')
[49, 53, 49]      # characters '1', '5', '1'
```